# Deriving joint cdf for two random variables X and Y from joint pdf

Tags: probability, statistics

Find the joint cdf $F(x,y)$ for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose joint pdf is given by 
$f(x,y) = \frac 1 2$ , $0 \le x \le y \le 2$.

I know that I have to integrate with respect to $x$ as well as $y$. What I am having problems with is the bounds. Can someone please explain how I am supposed to figure that out?

Comment: Draw many graphs with the dominion of the pdf and the integration area.

Comment: @ImanolN. I'm not sure what you mean by "integration area".

Comment: It would be the area where the integral will be computed. It should be something like $(-\infty, a) \times (-\infty, b)$ for $F_{X, Y}(a, b)$.

Comment: No @Imanol N. it is the triangle $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 2$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Defining the joint pdf with the indicator function the area is like I said.

Comment: @Imanol N. I agree : nobody is wrong in the affair...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sketch of the support of the pdf and the cdf, and a geometrical computation of $F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)=\frac12y_0-\frac14x_0^2$ (check it, it is a good exercice).

It can help to understand why, for example concerning the marginal in $X$, we integrate with respect to $y$ (this is general) with  the integration bounds $x_0$ and $2$ (this is particular):

$$f_X(x_0)=\int_{y=x_0}^{y=2}f(x,y)dy=\int_{y=x_0}^{y=2}\dfrac12dy=\dfrac12(2-x_0)$$

and a similar computation for $f_Y(y_0)=\int_{x=0}^{x=y_0}f(x,y)dy=\cdots.$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First: Ensure the bounds always lay within the maximums and minimums of $(0;2)\times(0;y)$

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int\limits_{0}^{\min\{2,y\}}\int\limits_{0}^{\min\{x,y, t\}} f_{X,Y}(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t\quad\mathbf 1_{x\geq 0, y\geq 0}$$

Next: split into disjoint cases to avoid having max and min in the integral trees.   Start out and move in.

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 0 & : x<0 ~\vee~ y<0 \\ 
 \int\limits_{0}^{y}\int\limits_{0}^{\min\{x, y, t\}} f_{X,Y}(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0\leq y<2 ~\wedge~ 0\leq x  \\
 \int\limits_{0}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\min\{x, 2, t\}} f_{X,Y}(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 2\leq y~ \wedge~ 0\leq x
\end{cases}$$

Finally: Do likewise for the inner integrals.

Hint: You should end up with five cases.